# Triple integral with tetrahedron

Tags: calculus

$$\iiint xyz \,dV$$ T is the solid tetrahedron with vertices (0,0,0) (1,0,0) (1,1,0) (1,0,1).

How do I figure out what z=f(x,y) is with these points? The equation of a tetrahedron is x/a+y/b+z/c=1

But with the 4 points given I don't know how to use the formula.

Comment: The equation you mention is for a plane, not a tetrahedron. You must obtain the equation of the plane passing through $((0,0,0), (1,1,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$ (sketch the tetrahedron and you'll see why). The integral becomes $\int_0^1\int_0^x \int_0^{ax+by+c} xyz dz \, dy\, dx$. You just need to compute a,b,c.

Comment: @PierreCarre Why those points ? Why not (0,0,0) (1,0,0) (1,1,0)? Or any of the other combinations you can make with the 4 points?

Comment: @AkashPatel No this is not a duplicate. The points are not even the same.

Comment: You have to draw the tetrahedron to see which of the four points lie on the surface.

Comment: @ John Wayland Bales , @PierreCarre Thank you !

Comment: Note that the equation of the plane which you gave is only valid for planes which do not contain the origin, since $a,b,c$ are the $x,y,z$ intercepts and cannot equal $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have three points $A(0,0,0), C(1,1,0)$ and $B(1,0,1)$ lying on the plane $z=f(x,y)$, so you need to find a direction vector for the plane.

Two vectors lying in the plane are $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$ and their cross-product gives you a normal vector $(-1,1,1)$. Using the plane equation

$$ a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0 $$

where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point of the plane and $(a,b,c)$ is a normal vector we get, using point $(1,1,0)$

$$ -(x-1)+(y-1)+z=0 $$

Therefore

$$z = x-y$$

[image: Tetrahedron]

Comment: Note that if you know that the volume of a cone is one-third the product of the area of the base times the height, then you know that you should obtain a volume of one-third of one-half, that is, one-sixth.